# Python 3.6 async await without asyncio: how to write own simplest event loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

Just like to understand `async await` syntax, so I am looking for some 'hello world' app without using asyncio at all.

So how to create simplest event loop using only Python syntax itself? The simplest code (from this [Start async function without importing the asyncio package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585935/start-async-function-without-importing-the-asyncio-package) , further code is much more then hello world, that's why I am asking) looks like that:

```
async def cr():
    while(True):
        print(1)

cr().send(None)
```

It prints `1` infinitely, not so good.

So the 1st question is how to yield from coroutine back to the main flow? `yield` keyword makes coroutine async generator, not we expected.

I would also appreciate a simple application, like this
i.e. we have a coroutine which prints 1, then yields to event loop, then prints 2 then exits with return 3, and simple event loop, which push coroutine until return and consume result.

Comment: Is this really the right approach for you? I think there must be other ways for you to learn the `async await` syntax, that don't require you to implement your own version of `asyncio`

Comment: Hope if i'll got what is under the hood, I'll got the concept itself. Without it looks like pure magic.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you will be happier if you embrace encapsulation and learn APIs and interfaces instead of internals, at least at first. There's nothing wrong with looking at the internals, but I think that is learning the `async await` pattern the very hard way. The metaphor I was taught was to think of a lightswitch when we talk about encapsulation: it is easier to learn how to use a lightswitch than how the wires fit together behind the panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
import types

@types.coroutine
def simple_coroutine():
    print(1)
    yield
    print(2)
    return 3

future = simple_coroutine()
while True:
    try: future.send(None)
    except StopIteration as returned:
        print('It has returned', returned.value)
        break
```

I think your biggest problem is that you're mixing concepts. An async function is not the same as a coroutine. It is more appropriate to think of it as a way of combining coroutines. Same as ordinary `def` functions are a way of combining statements into functions. Yes, Python is highly reflective language, so `def` is also a statement, and what you get from your async function is also a coroutine---but you need to have something at the bottom, something to start with. (At the bottom, yielding is just `yield`ing. At some intermediate level, it is `await`ing---of something else, of course.) That's given to you through the `types.coroutine` decorator in the standard library.

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.